# Assign each line of file to be a variable

Tags: bash

I am looking to assign each line of a file, through stdin a specific variable that can be used to refer to that exact line, such as line1, line2

example:

```
cat Testfile
Sample 1 -line1
Sample 2 -line2
Sample 3 -line3
```

Comment: Is `line1` a proposed variable name, or a part of the file?

Comment: In general, the right way to do this is with an array, **not** with variable indirection.

Comment: i=0
while read line; do
 ((i++))
 varname="$i"
 printf  "$2"
done

Comment: line1 would be the variable name. How could i go about doing it with an array?

Answer (score 12):

The wrong way to do this, but exactly what you asked for, using discrete variables:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf -v "line$(( ++i ))" '%s' "$line"
done <Testfile
echo "$line1" # to demonstrate use of array values
echo "$line2"
```

The right way, using an array, for bash 4.0 or newer:

```
mapfile -t array <Testfile
echo "${array[0]}" # to demonstrate use of array values
echo "${array[1]}"
```

The right way, using an array, for bash 3.x:

```
declare -a array
while read -r; do
  array+=( "$REPLY" )
done <Testfile
```

See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for more in-depth discussion.

Comment: +1 for demonstrating it with different `bash` versions.

Answer (score 6):

`bash` has a builtin function to do that.  `readarray` reads lines from a stdin (which can be your file) and assigns them elements of an array:

```
declare -a lines
readarray -t lines <Testfile
```

Thereafter, you can refer to the lines by number.  The first line is `"${lines[0]}"` and the second is `"${lines[1]}"`, etc.

`readarray` requires `bash` version 4 ([released in 2009](http://linux.slashdot.org/story/09/02/23/1957244/bash-40-released)), or better and is available on many modern linux systems.  Debian stable, for example, currently provides `bash` 4.2 while [RHEL6](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/sect-Migration_Guide-Package_Changes-Bash.html) provides 4.1.  Mac OSX, though, is still using`bash` 3.x.

Comment: Only gotcha here is that `readarray` (like its synonym `mapfile`) was added fairly recently, and is unavailable on systems shipping bash 3.x such as OS X and RHEL5/CentOS 5.

Comment: To assign output of a program to an array, do `readarray -t lines < <(program_that_writes_to_stdout)`